# Using jQuery to loop through JSON Array and output data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm working on something at the moment to call a PHP file to get some XML data and convert and return as JSON array data which works great and I'm getting and displaying that data however there is one part of the array which I need to loop through to display  but stuck with how I do that.

Here is  an example json data:

```
{
   "TrackingRecord":{
      "Authorised":"Authorised(5.77.48.131)",
      "DeliveryAddress":{
         "CompanyName":"JAMES DERICK",
         "Address1":"6",
         "Address2":"LIBER HOUSE",
         "Address3":"OLYMPIAN",
         "Town":"YORK",
         "Postcode":"YO10 3UF",
         "ContactName":"JAMES DERICK",
         "ContactTelephone":"7507346318"
      },
      "CollectionAddress":{
         "CompanyName":"AMBIENT LOUNGE LTD",
         "Address1":"UNIT 3 LONG HEDGE LANE INDUSTR",
         "Address2":"BOTTESFORD",
         "Address3":{

         },
         "Town":"NOTTINGHAM",
         "Postcode":"NG13 0BF",
         "ContactName":"SARAH KIRBY",
         "ContactTelephone":"07879 442266074"
      },
      "ConsignmentInformation":{
         "Pieces":"1",
         "Pallets":"0",
         "Weight":"10",
         "Service":"Priority 1",
         "DeliveryDate":"2016-02-29T00:00:00",
         "ItemsDelivered":"1",
         "ConsignmentRef":"2838",
         "SpecialInstructions":"JAMES DERICK 7507346318 {JAMES\u003Cbr\u003E14075@GMAIL.COM}\u003Cbr\u003E",
         "AdditionalReferencesInformation":{
            "AdditionalReferences":{
               "Reference":"2838"
            }
         }
      },
      "MovementInformation":{
         "Movement":[
            {
               "MovementDate":"2016-02-25T00:00:00",
               "MovementTime":"0001-01-01T10:00:04",
               "Description":"Created By EZEEWEB",
               "DeliveryDepot":"Leeds",
               "Round":"019",
               "DeliveryDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "PackagesReceived":"0",
               "PackagesDelivered":"0"
            },
            {
               "MovementDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "MovementTime":"0001-01-01T07:11:53",
               "Description":"Out to deliver",
               "DeliveryDepot":"Leeds",
               "Round":"019",
               "DeliveryDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "PackagesReceived":"1",
               "PackagesDelivered":"0"
            },
            {
               "MovementDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "MovementTime":"0001-01-01T11:00:53",
               "Description":"Failed - Other reason",
               "DeliveryDepot":"Leeds",
               "Round":"019",
               "DeliveryDate":"2016-02-29T00:00:00",
               "PackagesReceived":"1",
               "PackagesDelivered":"0"
            },
            {
               "MovementDate":"2016-02-27T00:00:00",
               "MovementTime":"0001-01-01T05:59:32",
               "Description":"Out to deliver",
               "DeliveryDepot":"Leeds",
               "Round":"019",
               "DeliveryDate":"2016-02-29T00:00:00",
               "PackagesReceived":"1",
               "PackagesDelivered":"0"
            },
            {
               "MovementDate":"2016-02-29T00:00:00",
               "MovementTime":"0001-01-01T10:55:43",
               "Description":"Delivered",
               "DeliveryDepot":"Leeds",
               "Round":"019",
               "DeliveryDate":"2016-02-29T00:00:00",
               "PackagesReceived":"1",
               "PackagesDelivered":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      "TimedInformation":{
         "TimedDelivery":{
            "Signature":"DERICK",
            "SignatureDate":"2016-02-29T00:00:00",
            "SignatureTime":"0001-01-01T10:55:00"
         }
      },
      "ScanInformation":{
         "Scan":[
            {
               "PieceID":"148426702251072001",
               "Description":"Auto Inbound Scan   ()",
               "Depot":"Newark",
               "ScanDate":"2016-02-25T00:00:00",
               "ScanTime":"0001-01-01T17:12:01",
               "ScannedBy":"NWK CONVYR"
            },
            {
               "PieceID":"148426702251072001",
               "Description":"Auto Inbound Scan   ()",
               "Depot":"Leeds",
               "ScanDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "ScanTime":"0001-01-01T02:22:08",
               "ScannedBy":"LDS CONVYR"
            },
            {
               "PieceID":"148426702251072001",
               "Description":"Load C & D          (019)",
               "Depot":"Leeds",
               "ScanDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "ScanTime":"0001-01-01T03:37:45",
               "ScannedBy":"CJONES"
            },
            {
               "PieceID":"148426702251072001",
               "Description":"Load C & D          (019)",
               "Depot":"Leeds",
               "ScanDate":"2016-02-26T00:00:00",
               "ScanTime":"0001-01-01T23:43:22",
               "ScannedBy":"CJONES"
            }
         ]
      },
      "ImageInformation":{
         "PODImage":{
            "URL":"http:\/\/www.tpeweb.co.uk\/ezpod\/tpenas\/valid\/20160229\/014842672838___________00000_01.tif"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Snippet of JS:

```
<div id="tracking">
      <div class="delivery"></div>
      <div class="movement"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
       var account = getUrlParameter('account');
       var reference = getUrlParameter('reference'); 
       $.ajax({
         url: 'http://www.ambientlounge.com/external/ukTracking.php',
         type: 'POST', 
         dataType: "json",
         data: {
           account: account,
           reference: reference
         }, 
         success: function(json){
           $('#tracking .delivery').html(
             "<h3>Delivery Details</h3><p>Name: " + json["TrackingRecord"]["DeliveryAddress"]["CompanyName"] + "<br /><h5>Address:</h5>" + json["TrackingRecord"]["DeliveryAddress"]["Address1"] + "<br />" + json["TrackingRecord"]["DeliveryAddress"]["Address2"] + "<br />" + json["TrackingRecord"]["DeliveryAddress"]["Address3"] + "<br />" + json["TrackingRecord"]["DeliveryAddress"]["Town"] + "<br />" + json["TrackingRecord"]["DeliveryAddress"]["Postcode"] + "</p>"
           );
           for (var i = 0; i < json["MovementInformation"]["Movement"].length; i++) {
             console.log(json); // stuck here if im doing right at all!
           }
         }
       });
    });

    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
      var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
          sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
          sParameterName,
          i;

      for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
          sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

          if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
              return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
          }
      }
    };

    </script>
```

At the moment I am just grabbing the "DeliveryAddress" data which works fine, as nothing to loop through those but I'm at the point now where I have multiple points in the array "MovementInformation" > "Movement" which has multiple parts I need to loop through and display, but no idea how to do this.

Comment: Try `for (var i = 0; i < json.MovementInformation.Movement.length; i++) {console.log(json.MovementInformation.Movement[i]);}`

Comment: @James just curious, why you are converting `xml` to `json` even you can `parse` `xml` with `jquery`?

Comment: Dont know, i might be doing long way around... its to pull data into shopify but i think when i tried i was getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error and so far only found best way is to create a php file on one of my servers and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin for the domain and use file_get_contents and pass back to jquery on the shopify template to get data.

Comment: As a side note; When you allow to a new domain for access control, ajax can work with xml too. Btw good luck with your problem.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this access control thing within setting those allowed domains in the php file for file get contents to use on ajax request from other domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json.TrackingRecord.MovementInformation.Movement.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item)
})
```

Comment: i copy and pasted your json data, then did a foreach to get each item and worked. strange

Comment: make sure you have the console open

Comment: Yep sorry console shows the magic  haha - could you maybe help me with  updating the fiddle so its in a table and loops through so does like each row as <tr></tr> with the data in each of its own <td></td> so i can display data in table format? sorry to ask just so stuck as almost 11pm on sunday and need to demo monday in office lol

Comment: check update 2 i made a start... think in right direction :)

Comment: haha im a quick learner :) see what i done here: https://jsfiddle.net/yc6s43uv/3/ - just working out how to format date / time stuff

Comment: Any ideas how to format MovementDate and MovementTime better?

Comment: Ideally want to avoid any plugins as its a shopify template and want to reduce load but will check it out, can new Date not be of some use?

Comment: Ahh thanks mate, yea think can work... is it possible to add the year? either 2016 or 16? and I have just added the MovementTime is there anyway to format that? again thanks for all your help! promise this would be the last bit ;) https://jsfiddle.net/3kfzfvd0/1/

Comment: Oh i saw you added for year but not in output so i added, just need time now... here is updated: https://jsfiddle.net/3kfzfvd0/2/

Comment: I know might be more complicated so dont worry if it is, but is there anyway in the loop / or if possible in  jquery can sort so the latest date is top of loop rather than latest date at bottom? Thanks again for all your help! no idea how much is helping me for delivery / demo in morning with boss haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105513/discussion-between-akis-tfs-and-james).